# How can a Linux source package be opened as a project in an IDE?

Tags: linux, ide, makefile, compilation, package

I am makeing a small mod to SMPlayer; the Linux version...
The `make`, `sudo make install` from the command line works, but I would like to have the project in an IDE.

I want to use CodeBlocks IDE, only because I've used it before, but if some other IDE is required, I can use that instead... (I use Codeblocks because it is simple, and that suits my current ability to handle an IDE)..

Is there some way to use SMPlayer's Makefile, or some such thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code::Blocks has builtin support for Makefile projects. See [the FAQ](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ#Q%3a_My_project_should_be_compiled_with_a_custom_makefile._Is_it_possible_with_Code%3a%3aBlocks.3F).

Also you could just use vim or emacs ;)

Comment: I'm tantalizingly close now, but when I 'build' Codeblocks pops up a message `make: *** No rule to make target `cleanRelease'.` and likewise for the Debug target... I'll have to play around with it a bit more.. You've certainly put me on the right track.. and I like your suggestion about using emacs, which I have just started using. I suspect that `vim` and `emacs` may be more attuned to this type of Linux package ... It's a big learning curve, but I may as well put the two curves together : )

Comment: @fred I bet Code::Blocks is trying to clean the project before building. Maybe it has a way for you to tell it what to do to clean... (I don't use Code::Blocks, vim all the way :D)

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the IDE and has little to nothing to do with Linux.

Does your program come with something like cmake or another setup tool? That normally makes it much easier. For example in KDevelop you can import straight from CMakeLists.txt and Makefiles.

If all else fails it might be quite easy to do something like this (not knowing your specific IDE):

1. Add new Project
2. Set build directory and other necessary settings (like compiler and compiler flags)
3. Add the already existing files to it.
4. Press "Compile"-button.

This is obviously depending on the project structure, setup and size.

Comment: Your "other" solution won't work if it has excess dependencies, dynamic code generation, a configuration solution that generates a config.h, or any other oddities.

Comment: Your 1,2,3,4 steps were useful.. I've never done that before... I've only ever dabbled in my own programs.... It seems that directories may be my problem now, but as it didn't work directly, I'll have a look at mathepic's vim/emacs suggestion ..